# Implementing bootstrap validation state to a text_field

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a form in ROR and I'd like to use a bootstrap validation state on the text_field but I'm unsure of how to implement the feature? I'm not great with bootstrap so I thought I see if I could get help on here. I'll show my form and my code for clarity.

FORM

```
<label>
Name<br>
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
</label>
```

Here I have already placed the div class around the text_field but how does bootstrap know when a validation is wrong and turn the text field red? Im trying to implement this

```
  <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError2">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError2" aria-describedby="inputError2Status">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputError2Status" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
  </div>
```

this is in the bootstrap docs but I'm not sure how to make it work in my app

I want the text field to look like this when name is blank.

[image]

I hope this is enough info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your errors in your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, above the yield and under your nav.

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% elsif flash[:error] %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= flash[:error] %>
  </div>
<% elsif flash[:alert] %>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= flash[:alert] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

within your model, validate the form

```
validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
```

within app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
 def form_group_tag(errors, &block)
 if errors.any?
   content_tag :div, capture(&block), class: 'form-group has-error'
 else
   content_tag :div, capture(&block), class: 'form-group'
 end
end
```

within your form

```
    <% if post.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <h4>There are <%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
       <ul>
         <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:title]) do %>
     <%= f.label :title %>
     <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:body]) do %>
     <%= f.label :body %>
     <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

make sure you have the proper logic in your controller too

```
if @book.save
    format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This example here might be helpful: http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-warning-validation-state/

Answer (score 0):

In Rails the easyest way to do it is using te gem [bootstrap_form](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms)

after install it you can use it like this

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Log In" %>
<% end %>
```

hope this helps